# Copying cells from a range in one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet which contains data for several individuals for different dates.  I'd like to copy the non-zero cells to a separate sheet for each individual.  For example, Tom worked 3 hours on 4/12, 6 hours on 4/13, and 5 hours on 4/16.  Dick worked 6 hours on 4/12, 3 hours on 4/15, and 5 hours on 4/16.  Harry worked 5 hours on 4/14, 4 hours on 4/15, and 6 hours on 4/16.  Column A has the dates 4/12 through 4/16, and columns C, D, and E have the hours that Tom, Dick, and Harry worked on those days.  Days they did not work are left blank.  I have a separate worksheet for each person, which should only show the days that they worked, so Tom's sheet would have the dates 4/12, 4/13, and 4/16 only.  Is there a macro or lookup I can use to copy from the master sheet to the individual's sheets?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this (and is in a worksheet named "Master"):

[image]

Give this code a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMstr As Worksheet
    Dim rngHours As Range
    Dim cIndex As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMstr = wb.Sheets("Master")
    Set rngHours = wsMstr.UsedRange

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For cIndex = Columns("C").Column To rngHours.Columns.Count
        With wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            .Name = wsMstr.Cells(rngHours.Row, cIndex).Text
            rngHours.AutoFilter cIndex, ">0"
            Intersect(rngHours, wsMstr.Range("A:A," & Columns(cIndex).Address)).Copy .Range("A1")
            rngHours.AutoFilter
            .Columns("A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    Next cIndex
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```